# Applying tensorflow on streaming data

Tags: tensorflow, streaming

**How can we apply tensorflow for streaming data?**

I need to apply tensorflow for streaming data which comes in json format. But, still I couldn't find any way to do that.

Comment: what do you mean by streaming data?

Comment: Streaming data are the data that comes continuously . Example: data that comes from a temperature sensor.